# A new lower bound for the chromatic number of a graph?

Tags: graph-theory, graph-colorings, spectral-graph-theory

Let $S_{+}(G)$ denote the sum of the squares of the positive eigenvalues of the adjacency matrix of a graph $G$. Let $S_{-}(G)$ denote the sum of the squares of the negative eigenvalues and $q$ the chromatic number. 
Is it true that $1 + \frac{S_{+}(G)}{S_{-}(G)} \leq q$?

The chromatic number cannot be replaced with the clique number in this conjecture, because the Coxeter graph provides a counter-example. This bound is incomparable with the Hoffman lower bound for the chromatic number.

UPDATE: Ando and Lin have proved this conjecture in "Proof of a conjectured lower bound on the chromatic number of a graph", to be published soon in Linear Algebra and its Applications. They also prove that $1 + \frac{S_{-}(G)}{S_{+}(G)} \leq q$.

Comment: Dear Clive, did you test your inequality for any class of trees or $K_n -{e_1,e_2,...,e_t}$ for some suitable $t$?

Comment: I think about Kneser graphs. We know that for Kneser graph $K_{n:r}$, $q=n-2r+2$ and $m=Cr(n,r)Cr(n-r,r)/2$. Also the eigenvalues of these graphs are determined and are $(-1)^i \times Cr(n-r-i,r-i)$. I think for suitable $n$(sufficiently large)  and $r$ you can find a counter example for this inequality. 

Comment: Dear Shahrooz, I have tested the conjecture against all named graphs in Wolfram Mathematica 8.0 with up to 50 vertices and found no counter-examples. I have proved the conjecture for KG(n:r) for r = 1,2,3,4. For r > 4 the algebra gets tortuous! What makes you think for large n and r there will be a counter-example? Thanks Clive    

Comment: Just curious - to which journal did you submit the paper?

Comment: Stylistically, it is unclear to me which is better: to edit the question and provide a clearly marked update, or to submit an answer which contains an updated answer?  Either is better than your current edit.  I suggest adding the word "Update" to the start of the relevant paragraph.  Gerhard "Ask Me About System Design" Paseman, 2012.09.21

Comment:  You probably want the graph to have at least one edge otherwise $S−=0$. Also, is there a quick way to see that $S+/S−$ is unbounded?

Comment: You should register an account, so you don't keep creating new user IDs.

Comment: In an answer that I have deleted, Clive wrote: "Pawel and I have submitted our paper to The Electronic Journal of Combinatorics. We do need to exclude the empty graph and the conjectured bound is unbounded because it is exact for complete graphs."

Comment: The above-cited paper of Clive Elphick and Pawel Wojcan seems to be this one: http://www.combinatorics.org/ojs/index.php/eljc/article/view/v20i3p39 .  The paper of Ando and Lin is here http://web.uvic.ca/~linm/chromatic.pdf